# Wordpress permalinks won't work after migrating website from xampp windows to apache2 ubuntu

Tags: wordpress, apache2, permalinks, php-7.4

Wordpress 6.0, Php 7.4, Webserver Apache2, MySql working fine

Website works just fine using the same settings and same files on **xampp windows**,
when running it on **ubuntu apache2** permalinks do not work properly.
Remember that I used 2 IDENTICAL COPIES running on different systems. I already tried to reset .htacess and played a bit with permanent links but no results. DNS records are formed by 2 rules, both A pointing from domain.com and [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) to server ip.
Also When I try to **save an post (article) it errors with "Update fail. Response is not JSON valid"**

Expected behavior -Display requested page domain/%postname%/

Actual behavior -Error 404 not found

Active Theme:
MentalPress WP Theme

Enabled modules:

1. Advanced Custom Fields: Repeater Field
2. Akismet anti-spam
3. Black Studio TinyMCE Widget
4. Disable Emojis (GDPR friendly)
5. Disable XML-RPC
6. Envato Market
7. Contact Form 7
8. Hello Dolly
9. Page Builder by SiteOrigin
10. ProteusWidgets
11. ShortPixel Image Optimizer
12. Simple Lightbox
13. SiteOrigin Widgets Bundle
14. Wordfence Security
15. WP Bing Map Pro
16. WP Rocket
17. WP-Sweep
18. Yoast SEO

Comment: You probably have not installed or activated apache2's mod_rewrite module in your ubuntu setup. WordPress uses that for permalinks. See step 3 of this. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-a-lamp-stack

Answer (score 0):

Explained bellow all the issues that can makes this kind of problem.

**First, please make sure your all the files permission is correct**.
Then make sure your permalink is set as postname (To check go to **Admin dashboard > Settings > Permalink**)

Then please fix your siteurl. You can choose anyone of the 2 solutions:

1. To change the siteurl and home fields from your database go to **phpmyadmin**. Then go to **your database > wp_options** and then change the **siteur**l and **home** according to your domain.
2. You can add the two constant in wp_config.php file.

   ```
     define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
     define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
   ```

Thank you